# Python Selenium CORS Error though Real browser works well

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I use the selenium on python.

When I visit the page on real browser, it works well.

Link: https://www.wyndhamhotels.com/days-inn/alexander-city-alabama/days-inn-alexander-city/rooms-rates

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1ulxa1h

Btw, When I visit the same page on selenium browser, it took CORs error, and It does not display the content.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1ulxk6c

Could anyone tell me how can fix this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can disable [cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors) errors by using `--disable-web-security` options argument, try below code

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-web-security") 
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually, I tried with that argument, then driver did not display cors error on console log, but the content still was not displayed.

Comment: did you tried with latest version of chrome, above mentioned url working on chrome 94

Comment: yes. I use 94 version chrome now